# Attaching onchange function event to variable

Tags: javascript, closures, onchange

I recently got into closures and anonymous functions, and I'm wondering if my code is the right way to do it (it works!):

```
newInput.onchange = function(x){
     return function(){
          PassFileName(x);  
     }
}(counter);
```

so this is in a loop that "saves" the current 'counter' value (1,2,3...). If I didn't have the return function, then 'counter' will always be the last value of 'counter'.

Am I approaching this correctly with that code? or is there a better way to "capture" the current counter and attach it to an onchange event?

thank you!

Comment: One caution with this approach is the useless closures that are created and persist as long as the function remains a listener. Make sure the outer functions don't needlessly hang onto references to bulky objects or variables. Implementations may (and some do) optimise them away when there are no references to things in the outer scope, but it was once a great way to create memory leaks in IE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you're approaching it correctly, but for maximum compatibility with implementations, you need to put parentheses around the function:

```
    newInput.onchange = (function(x){
//                      ^--- here
         return function(){
              PassFileName(x);  
         }
    })(counter);
//   ^--- and here
```

Whenever you're doing a function expression and calling it immediately, you need those parens because there's a parsing ambiguity otherwise.

---

**Update**:

While your approach is fine, it's worth pointing out that it's a bit profligate. ;-) It creates *two* functions on every iteration of your loop, the outer anonymous one, and the inner anonymous one. Both of those functions stick around (barring implementation optimisations, which you know Some Engines won't have). Instead, you could have just one per loop plus one factory function:

```
// In the loop
newInput.onchange = makeHandler(x);

// Outside the loop
function makeHandler(x){
     return function(){
          PassFileName(x);  
     };
}
```

Some may consider it easier to read (I certainly do), provided the `makeHandler` is still close enough to the loop that you don't lose track.

Using a factory function also offers you the opportunity of not closing over anything *else* in scope, although then you have to put the factory function further away (e.g., in a well-contained scope).

You might also consider a generic [curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) function, like [the one provided by Prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Function/prototype/curry/). A generic `curry` that *doesn't* pass on call-time arguments looks like this:

```
function curry(f) {
    var args = arguments;
    return function() {
        f.apply(undefined, args);
    };
}
```

But it's usually more helpful (but more expensive) to have one that *does* pass on the runtime arguments as well. Here's a cheap-and-dirty (not optimised; with optimisation call-time overhead can be markedly reduced):

```
function curry(f) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function() {
        f.apply(undefined,
                args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
}
```

The advantage in both cases is that you're not closing over anything new that you can avoid.

---

**Off-topic**: Also, *technically*, you're relying on the horror that is semicolon insertion (there should be a semicolon at the end of your `return` statement), which I always advocate not relying on. Pretty darned safe in this example, though. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is fairly standard, and there's nothing wrong with it. However, there's a similar method which I prefer:

```
(function (x) {
    newInput.onchange = function () {
        PassFileName(x);
    };
})(counter);
```

To me, it is clearer by wrapping the whole block (and with the indentation) that I'm deliberating creating a new scope in order to capture the value of a variable.

Comment: Agreed that's clearer. See @RobG's point above, though. Doing it that way means that an implementation almost certainly *can't* optimize away the outer function because it (now) has something on its variable object (the `x` argument) that the inner function requires. @wata's way at least gives the engine the chance of optimising the redundant factory functions away...

Comment: @T.J. I agree about the excess functions being created, and your `makeHandler` update is certainly is a better option (+1 on that!), if your needs go beyond some quick and dirty code. I don't understand how automatic optimisation can differ between my example and @wata's though?

Comment: @Box9: Yeah, it's tricky. :-) When you call a function, an *execution context* is created. An execution context has an associated *variable object* which has properties for each argument, each `var`, and each result of a function *declaration* (not function expressions). That variable object is put at the top of the scope chain, which is used to resolve unqualified references (like `x`). This is how closures work, functions keep a reference to the variable object (which in turn references the next in the chain, etc.). *(cont'd)*

Comment: @Box9: *(continuing)*  In @wata's version, the variable object for the call to the outer function will be blank, but in yours it will have an `x` property for the `x` argument to the outer function. An optimizer is more likely to be able to figure out that it can throw away a function with an empty variable object (and the variable object, and the execution context) than if the variable object has something on it. When I say "blank," the variable object is never *truly* blank (it has a property called `arguments` at the very least), but let's say, blank other than stuff it always has. :-)

Comment: @T.J. thanks for the explanation. I understand what you're saying about the variable object, but in @wata's version, the outer function has an argument `x` as well. So why is the variable object "blank" in this case?

Comment: @Box9: *"So why is the variable object "blank" in this case?"* Er, um, it isn't. I totally got my head screwed on backward. :-) For some reason I was thinking the outer function in @wata's case *didn't* have that argument, but of course it does, and it has to. Sorry about that, no difference at all. *sigh* Still, it was a nice academic discussion, eh?