# setting events programmatically

Tags: javascript

I am setting the className of a table row in my code, is it possible to do something similiar to set an event on a row?  This is along the lines of what I would like to do :

```
for (var i = 1; i < numRows; i++) {
            var ID = table.rows[i].id;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                table.rows[i].className = "GridRow";
                table.rows[i].onmouseout = "GridRow";
            }
            else {
                table.rows[i].className = "GridRowAlt";
                table.rows[i].onmouseout = "GridRowAlt";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can assign a function instance to the event handler that way:

```
table.rows[i].onmouseout = function() { ... };
```

Be careful doing that in loops, because you're creating a new function on every loop and the function closes over the data in scope (and so has an *enduring reference* to it, not a copy of it as of when the function was created; see [this other recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744701/attaching-onchange-function-event-to-variable) for more). But don't worry, [closures are not complicated](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) once you understand how they work.

In general, this is called "DOM0" event handling because it involves a method of attaching event handlers that was created prior to the first DOM specification. As of DOM2, there's a better way [`addEventListener`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener):

```
table.rows[i].addEventListener('mouseout',function() { ... }, false);
```

It's "better" because you can have more than one event handler on the same event of the same element, whereas with the DOM0 mechanism, assigning a new event handler disconnects the previous one (if any).

On IE prior to IE9, sadly, `addEventListener` wasn't supported but it did have the *very similar* [`attachEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
table.rows[i].attachEvent('onmouseout',function() { ... });
```

Note the differences:

- `addEventListener`'s event names don't have the "on" prefix
- `addEventListener` has one more param than `attachEvent`, which you almost always want to set `false`

---

**Update**:

All of the examples above are for inline anonymous functions, which is a bit unlike me, because [I don't like anonymous functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html). So just for clarity, from an events perspective, a function is a function. It can be a named function you declare elsewhere, or an inline anonymous function, whatever:

```
// Hook up...
table.rows[i].addEventListener('mouseout', handleRowMouseOut, false);

// Nice, reusable function defined elsewhere
function handleRowMouseOut(event) {
    // ...
}
```

---

**Off-topic**: It's these sorts of browser differences that lead me to geneerally recommend using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They smooth over differences for you as well as providing lots of handy utility functions.

Answer (score 0):

`table.rows[i].onmouseout = "GridRow";` doesn't make a lot of sense, `table.rows[i].onmouseout = function(){alert('hello');};` or some other valid script ought to work though.

Comment: My apologies, I am jumping around between Java, JavaScript and C++, make the odd mix up.

Comment: :-) Aren't we all. (Ooh, C++, must be fun to put *that* hat on and take it off, with the difference in memory handling...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: There is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or some other JavaScript framework? This way your code gets more simple.

```
var i = 0;

$('#some_table tr').each(function() {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('GridRow');
    $(this).mouseout(function(evt) { /* your GridRow function */ });
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('GridRowAlt');
    $(this).mouseout(function(evt) { /* your GridRowAlt function */ });
  }

  i++;
})
```

Sultan

Comment: That doesn't look markedly simpler to me. (There are lots of things jQuery and similar *do* make simpler, of course.) Side note: *Every time* you call `$(this)`, there are multiple function calls and a memory allocation required. If you find yourself writing `$(this)` more than once in a function, consider doing it once and storing the result. Oh, also, you don't need the `i` variable, just use the index that jQuery passes into the iterator function: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

The original question is not to alert "GridRow". I'm quit sure GridRow is a function name. Fortunately each function is a child of window so write window["GridRow"].

I would add a well known bind-event function, because you need it quite often.

```
var bindEvent=function(elem,evt,func){
              if(elem.addEventListener){
                 elem.addEventListener(evt,func,false);
              }
              else if(elem.attachEvent){
                      elem.attachEvent('on'+evt,function(){
                          func.call(event.srcElement,event); 
                       })
             }
};
```

and then:

```
bindEvent(table.rows[i],"mouseout",window["GridRow"]);
```