# JavaScript — Most performant no-op in mouse event listener?

Tags: javascript, performance, event-handling, event-delegation, no-op

#### Context

I am building a Redux application, and would like `click` and `mousemove` event handlers to change depending on application state.

To accomplish this, I am planning to attach a single `click` and single `mousemove` handler to the `document`. These will belong to a scope that subscribes to the Redux store, and knows the relevant state.

I see two strategies for implementing the handlers:

1. Use a `switch` statement against the relevant state variable. This `switch` would have to be called for each fired event.
2. Reference internal (to the scope) `scope._clickHandler` and `scope._moveHandler` properties that swap out their referents whenever the state is updated.

#### Question 1:

If I choose Strategy 2, I will want my `mousemove` handler to do nothing most of the time. But `mousemove` gets fired a lot! What is the most performant no-op function that could be bound to the `scope._moveHandler` property?

#### Question 2:

In the best case (w/r/t Question 1), would Strategy 2 be more performant than Strategy 1, assuming the `switch` statement used in Strategy 1 has to test between 10 and 100 cases?

#### Clarification

On this approach, one "delegating" function will always be called when an event fires. That function will do different thing depending on a state property, either by matching that state in a `switch` or simply by having different "delegee" functions bound *as* the state.

Question 1 asks about the optimal do-nothing "delegee" function, while Question 2 asks about the performance penalty incurred by having a large `switch` block in a `mousemove` callback.

If we as a community agree with @nnnnnn's intuition that `function(){}` is as good as it gets for a no-op, my question becomes:

**Which is worse for performance: the overhead for the no-op function call, or the equality comparisons in a `switch` block?**

Comment: 1. Check if it's not `null`, then call. No call is the cheapest call.

Comment: *"What is the most performant no-op function"* - If you assume a function *must* be called at all then wouldn't the most performant just be an empty function?

Comment: You could also set the event programmatically (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745191/setting-events-programmatically); whenever you need to change what `onclick` or `onmousemove` do, just get the element and set those properties (literally `element.onclick` or `element.onmousemove`) to the new function

Comment: @this-vidor well, if you don't have a handler - then don't attach anything at all to the component's `onMouseMove`.

Comment: @zerkms The purpose of this overall approach is to avoid having to manage adding/removing handlers— and therefore having to keep track of references to event handlers. But in other contexts you are of course correct.

Comment: @zerkms This is also not a React app, there is no component for me to re-render with a null or non-null `onMove` prop. Just Redux! As stated in the question, these event listeners are added to the `document`.

Comment: @nnnnnn That is exactly what I'm asking! Something like `function(){}` seems like a good candidate, but so does `function(){ return false; }`. And I can't set aside the possibility that JavaScript (or certain engines) have some builtin no-op symbol.

Comment: Returning `false` from an event handler actually has a specific effect that you don't want: it cancels the event's default behaviour.

Comment: @nnnnnn So is your answer to **Question 1**: `function(){}` ?

Comment: Yes, that's my common-sense, no-research-done-but-I-don't-see-how-anything-else-could-be-faster answer.

Comment: Something I've found useful when binding events for mousemove is to wrap them in lodash's throttle function: https://lodash.com/docs#throttle